# proof verification for pole at $\infty$ ,and entire implies polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

We have if $f$ is entire function with pole of order n at $\infty$ then it is polynomial of degree n.

$\textbf{proof:}$    Here f entire ,so we have Taylor expansion at 0

$f(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i} z^i$ for all $ z\in \mathbb C$ ;  $ a_{i}= \frac{f^{i}(0)}{i!}$

By definition of pole at $\infty $ and replacing $z$ by  $\frac{1}{z}$ we have

$f(\frac{1}{z})=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i} \frac{1}{ z^i}$ for all $ z\in \mathbb C-(0)$.

and now by uniqueness of Laurent expansion above is infact the Laurent expansion of $f(\frac{1}{z})$.

and pole at $\infty$ give pole at 0, so all $a_{i}=0 for i>n$ (as we have pole of order n at z=0).

and now easily f is polynomial of degree n ,.

is this proof correct?